# how to copy/upload a locally created file to azure file storage using PHP

Tags: php, azure

I'm trying to follow this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-file

with examples from this repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/samples/FileSamples.php#L235

The file is indeed copied to the azure server but the content aren't readable, to say the least, it takes a size but it's empty. This is only a text file as well, and what I plan to achieve after fixing this is to copy excel files generated via PHP to an azure file storage server.

Also, we are using file.core not blob.core

```
<?php

    require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\File\FileRestProxy;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Models\Range;

    $accountName = "test";
    $accountKey = "test";

    $shareName = 'test';

    $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$accountName;AccountKey=$accountKey";
    $fileClient = FileRestProxy::createFileService($connectionString);

    $dstfileName = 'demo-4.txt';
    $srcfileName = 'demo-4.txt';

    $sourcePath = sprintf(
        '%s%s/%s',
        (string)$fileClient->getPsrPrimaryUri(),
        $shareName,
        $srcfileName
    );

    try {
        // Create destination file.
        $fileClient->createFile($shareName, $dstfileName, 1024);
        // Copy file.
        return $fileClient->copyFile($shareName, $dstfileName, $sourcePath);
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code . ": " . $error_message . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

**Update using file_get_contents**

```
$srcfileName = 'demo-4.txt';

$content = file_get_contents('demo-4.txt');

$range = new Range(0, filesize('demo-4.txt') - 1);
$sourcePath = sprintf(
    '%s%s/%s',
    (string)$fileClient->getPsrPrimaryUri(),
    $shareName,
    $srcfileName
);

try {
    // Create source file.
    $fileClient->createFile($shareName, $srcfileName, 1024);

    $fileClient->putFileRange($shareName, $srcfileName, $content, $range);

} catch (ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code . ": " . $error_message . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This is able to create the file with the content from the source file, but the problem is that the range is incorrect since I don't know how to correctly get that value.

[image]

The created file is presented by the image attached, it has multiple nulls in it because I'm guessing my range exceeds the actual length of the source file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`createFile`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-file/src/File/FileRestProxy.php#L1553) method simply creates an empty file of size specified in the method call. It essentially maps to [`Create File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file) REST API operation.

You should use [`createFileFromContent`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-file/src/File/FileRestProxy.php#L2306) convenience method to create a file with content. It basically first creates an empty file and then writes the contents to that file.

Other option would be to call [`putFileRange`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/azure-storage-file/src/File/FileRestProxy.php#L2188) method to write the contents to the file after you have created it using `createFile` method.

Comment: I'm very new to this so I'm not sure how you pass the content if it's an excel file you're trying to create, since the example they have for content is just creating a random string which is fine for .txt files

Comment: Does the excel file you're trying to upload exist on your local computer (from where this code is running)?

Comment: that's the plan, PHP will create the excel file from DB data and send it over to azure.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the code for generating the excel file? I am assuming it will be done somewhere in your code above. Right?

Comment: sorry, don't have it yet but aye it will be somewhere above and I will store it locally in the server as well. since I'm using laravel it will be somewhere in public/assets/custom_dir. I'm still playing around with this so I didn't create that yet as I have yet to fully understand the azure part of things.

Comment: I have not used PHP so I am not sure if this is the right approach. If the file is stored on the local server, then you would read the file and get the file contents as stream (fopen may be?). That stream you need to pass to this createFileFromContent method. Give it a try please.

Comment: didn't know that's possible, do you have a document on what they refer to as content? I'll give that one a try as well. thank you

Comment: From the source code link I included in my answer: `@param  StreamInterface|resource|string   $content the content used to
     *                                                  create the file`. HTH.

Comment: I'm trying to use file_get_contents but I'm having a problem setting the file range, I'm not sure how to actually get the file range for the current file content I'm trying to put, can I get some pointers for this one?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written.

Comment: I've updated my question with the recent code using fiel_get_contents, my problem here is mostly in setting the range

Comment: Instead of using the two methods, can you try using just `createFileFromContent` method and pass the contents there?

Comment: Also regarding the problem you're facing, please change the following line of code `$fileClient->createFile($shareName, $srcfileName, 1024);` to `$fileClient->createFile($shareName, $srcfileName, filesize('demo-4.txt'));`. Basically you're creating a file of 1KB but putting content less than that. That's why you're seeing all those `NULL` values in the file. Otherwise your code is perfectly fine.

Comment: thank you, that did it, so I can just use filesize for setting the max range instead of using Psr7\stream_for($content)?

Comment: will you be able to enlighten me why they won't just use filesize but instead opt for stream_for in their samples?

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge in PHP is limited to none thus I won't be able to provide a good answer for that. Sorry :(.

Comment: no worries, but please update your question to include the answer for the file range since I assume that would be the problem for others as well. thank you :)